# Generic control to have inherit methods in WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, inheritance, designer

I have to work on a project on which there are several Form which have 80% of the code the same. So I try to create a generic class to make inheritate all my Forms of the UserControl class (the basic one) and my own class. But .Net doesn't support multi classs inheritance. So I create a middle class to do the inheritance chain like I can see on the net but I think I miss another step. Each class is in a different file for information.

The problem is I can't open anymore the designer for my initial Forms, because "Visual Studio cannot open a designer for the file because the class within it does not inherit from a class that can be visually designed".

Other information, I have a Mainwindow which inherite from "Form" and call one or another UserControl I design to show it.

What I had at the beginning :

```
namespace i2SIMDCProduction
{
    public partial class MyForm1 : UserControl
    {
        public MyForm1(MyOwnClass myClass)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.myClass = myClass;
        }
    }
}

namespace i2SIMDCProduction
{
    public partial class MyForm2 : UserControl
    {
        public MyForm2(MyOwnClass myClass)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.myClass = myClass;
        }
    }
}
```

What I have now :

```
namespace i2SIMDCProduction
{
    public partial class MyForm1 : MyMiddleClass
    {
        public MyForm1(MyOwnClass myClass)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.myClass = myClass;
        }
    }
}

namespace i2SIMDCProduction
{
    public partial class MyForm2 : MyMiddleClass
    {
        public MyForm2(MyOwnClass myClass)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.myClass = myClass;
        }
    }
}
namespace i2SIMDCProduction
{
    public partial class MyMiddleClass : UserControl
    {
        public void MethodForAllChild()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any kind of help. I tried different things already (create a third class at the top of the file of my Forms for example, create empty constructor, ...) but nothing which works for now. The more frustrating is it is compiling and working but only the designer is KO.

Comment: Does my MyMiddleClass has a parameterless constructor? To design a form the designer will instantiate the parent class via the parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Ralf how to see this ? I begin in C#/Winform. If I createmyself an empty parameterless constructor of MyMiddleClass, it does nothing more than before. For information, I added my class adding a "simple" class and not a Winform directly through the menu.

Comment: To see this you would need to debug visual studio. If you curios enough you could do that or just believe me that you need such a constructor for the designer ;) Visual Studio might still fail because the assembly MyMiddleClass is in might not be compiled and been taken up by the designer yet. Add the constructor, close any designer window, clean and rebuild your project, then try again.

Comment: Forms **should inherit from `Form`** There is nothing stopping you from creating `Form2` inherit from `Form1` which inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

Comment: @Ralf I added an empty constructor in my Middle class and rebuild after clean but still the same issue.

Comment: Tried your code(more or less) and works for me VS2019/Net 4.8. The thing with the needed constructor might be something old and seems to not be the case anymore.

Comment: I have the same version of VS/NET :( I think I didn't give enough information about my project but it is complicated and come from another developer so I discover little by little. Can you send me your projet please ? To test it on my computer and maybe start from there. I can give you my mail adress in private if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inheritance and designer in Windows Forms is a problem.

I have a Form with an splitter, two listboxes and some other controls. That form is used to translate (map) some items. You select one item at left, one at right and click button to match. They are the same item in different providers.

I have another provider that require some extra controls to do the translation. May be 90% or more of the code is the same, but I need some extra for this provider.

The options that I saw:

- Add these extra controls (protected or public) to the Form, hidden by default and without use. In Form derived class, you use them. You haven't the designer in derived Form, but you don't need because controls are in base Form. The problem with this approach is that the designer part of inheritance of derived Form is in base Form. It's a nonsense. I don't recomend this option.
- Don't use the designer in derived Form. Starting in the previous point, copy the designer code added for your derived Form into your derived Form and leave your base Form as at first stage, without nothing of derived Form. You don't use the designer but you can use it temporary, copy/paste and have a good inheritance... without the designer in derived Form. It's a good option if your derived Forms has few changes, few maintenance in the designer part.
- You can "Add" some logic to your base Form to allow extensions. For example, below of the ListBox, I can add a `Panel` (hidden by default) and some methods like `ShowLeftPanel/ShowRightPanel`. By default, these panels aren't used, but in derived class I can add an `UserControl` in left panel and show it. And that `UserControl` show the properties that I need to show in the special provider. Add some virtual methods for listbox selection changed, to update the `UserControl`. In this way, your `UserControl` has designer and also the base Form. You only need add some "extension points" in your form (a `Panel`, a `Splitter`...) and give some methods to interact with this parts of the base Form. And this is ok with inheritance because is something generic, like `Tag` property in controls.

**UPDATE**

Check this solution and tell me about it. Make your Forms like this:

```
public partial class MyForm1 : UserControl, IMyUserControl
{
    private readonly MyOwnClass myClass;

    public MyForm1(MyOwnClass myClass, MyMiddleClass myMiddle)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.myClass = myClass;
        this.MyMiddle = myMiddle;
    }

    public MyMiddleClass MyMiddle { get; }
}
```

In this way, all your panel's forms are `IMyUserControl`:

```
public class MyUserControl : IMyUserControl
{
    public MyMiddleClass MyMiddle { get; }
}
```

So, having any of your panel's form, you can cast to `IMyUserControl` and get the related `MyMiddleClass` having access to methods like `MethodForAllChild`:

```
public class MyMiddleClass
{
    public void MethodForAllChild()
    {
    }
}
```

In your main form, you may have some property or method that give you access to your `UserControl`. Create a method that give you the middle instance of the current `UserControl`:

```
private MyMiddleClass GetMyMiddle()
{
    UserControl userControl = GetYourMainFormCurrentUserControl();
    IMyUserControl myUserControl = userControl as IMyUserControl;
    return myUserControl?.MyMiddle;
}
```

And use it in your main form when you need:

```
MyMiddleClass myMiddle = GetMyMiddle();
if (myMiddle != null)
{
     myMiddle.MethodForAllChild();
}
```

In this way, you only need implement the interface and add a property in your forms/usercontrols. In the main form you can get this middleclass and the code to reuse is only in that class and shared in all places. You don't need copy/paste if you add or change something in the middle class.

**UPDATE 2**

I'm going to explain in other form how it works because the code is written above. The goal is having the code only in one place, without duplicate it.

You define an interface in a very similar way as a class but without implementation (this is not really true in lastest C# versions but we can suppose that is without code). C# don't allow multiple inheritance but you can derive from a class and implement as many interfaces as you want.

When we define `IMyUserControl` we are telling that every class that implements `IMyUserControl`, has a property `MyMiddle`. When `MyForm1` implements `IMyUserControl`, if you don't add the `MyMiddle` property, you get a compiler error. The key with this solution is that add and implement this interface in each form is very easy: add `IMyUserControl`, the property and a parameter in the constructor to set the property.

So, all your forms implements now `IMyUserControl`. I don't know where are your forms but it's sure that you have a way to get access to your `UserControl`. Maybe a variable or an array in which you add your user controls. You are working with them, so you can access to your user controls. Well, if you have an `UserControl` instance, and you know that your `UserControl` implements `IMyUserControl`, you can cast your `UserControl` to `IMyUserControl` and after the cast, you have access to the interface, in this case, to the `MyMiddle` property.

And we put in `MyMiddle` all the code that you want to share.

If you add some code of your main form, where you work with your forms, I can help you with the code. I haven't more code than existing in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your advices but I can't hide my 30 others panels in a main form. I have to stay with the same logic : one class per panel with the specific code, and a generic mother class which have all the methods which are the same for all panels.

Comment: I think John Alexiou answer may be the solution but I'm curious about your design. I appreciate if you give more information about your forms and why you need so many extra panels in the form. Are the 30 panels all of your panels or are there a single derived form that use 30 panels?

Comment: I get the source code from previous IT guy who is not anymore in the company. He created a MainWindow inherite from Form and in which there is a Panel in which I can show one of my 30 panels created separately. One panel = One step of the process. Like this, the GUI go from panel to another one step by step. My panel are for now WindowsForm which inherite from UserControl. My wish is to add a generic class between the panel and the UserControl class to have my methods which are for now copy/paste in each panel at only one place.

Comment: thank you for your update, but being newbie in C#, could you send me your project to better understand your solution having all the code at once ? Because you add something about an interface in it and I am discovering this so I am a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different forms to share the same visual controls on the screen then you set up inheritance between the forms.

Use the inherited form option in Visual Studio

[image: fig1]

For example, `Form1` has a group box, with a label and two text boxes

[image: scr1]

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void CommonMethod()
        {
        }
    }
```

and `Form2` inherits from `From1` and adds a list box

[image: scr2]

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form1
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        public void SpecificMethod()
        {
            base.CommonMethod();
        }

    }
```

As you can see the controls from `Form1` show up on `Form2` also with a little icon to indicate that they are inherited.

---

If instead you just need to share code (like business logic) and not visual controls, then you create a separate class to hold the code with a link to the parent form, and then each form should contain an instance of this class.

What you want to do is a Model-View-Controler setup, where the Model is only data-related classes, View is only UI code, and the controller goes between the two doing the heavy lifting with processing user inputs and updating values.

Comment: I didn't know that and I like it! Thank you man!

Comment: @Victor Another approach is the create a `UserControl` with the UI elements you want and the processing logic, and add this control to each form.

Comment: I know the UserControl approach but the inheritance that you show here it's very useful in some scenaries, better than UserControl option. I like so much to have learned this today.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou For me I want just a class with methods to inherit but in it there is a lot of methods which deals with control reference as argument. So, it is considered as a visual class ?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou on my side I have only UserControl and not Form as inheritage. It does a difference no ? I have already a Main Form which call one or another UserControl to show on it. Important information I think also ^^

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin - think containment instead of inheritance here. Have a common class that all your forms contain.

Comment: Seems to be a good option but a lot of works to transfer all methods from MainWindow to MyMiddleClass. I have to discuss it with my project manager. Thank you for all you advices !